# Uso, origen y connotación del adverbio "do"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, adverbios

Según el [Diccionario de la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=E1z0RhR%7CE1zbR6E), **do**, como adverbio tiene los siguientes significados:

> [**do**<sup>2</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=E1z0RhR%7CE1zbR6E)
>
> > *Contracc. de de<sup>2</sup> y o<sup>2</sup>.*
>
> 1. *adv. relat. desus.* **donde**. *U. en leng. poét.*
> 2. *adv. interrog. desus.* **dónde**.

En un himno cristiano he podido observar su uso, claramente toma una connotación poética y tiene una acepción referente a un lugar:

> *En la cruz, en la cruz,*
>   ***Do*** primero vi la luz,
>   *Y las manchas de mi alma yo lavé*
>   *Fue allí por fe **do** vi a Jesús,*
>   *Y siempre feliz con él seré.*

La RAE indica que está en desuso, pero quisiera saber si aún es propio usarlo en un escrito poético o narrativo.

También, según indica la RAE **do** proviene de la *"Contracción de **de** y **o**"* pero no toma su significado de esas palabras, pues significa ***"donde"***.

Fuera de ello quisiera saber su origen y su uso, tampoco se puede saber su frecuencia usando *Google Ngram*, puesto que se confunde con su otro significado.

Comment: en el escrito esta utilizado como "donde" pero ni idea de donde se utilice como "de" y "o". esa constraccion hace mas bien que suene a dominus o deos, tal vez es por eso que es utilizada tanto en esos cantos cristianos, pareciera que la siliaba "do" es la que los eclesiasticos mas aman

Comment: Romance de Fontefrida: "Fontefrida, fontefrida
fontefrida y con amor,
**do** todas las avecicas
van tomar consolación,
sino es la tortolica,             
que está viuda y con dolor..." Es un romance novelesco, el origen del cual no es muy exacto. Se atribuye al Romancero Viejo, entre los siglos XIII – XIV. Se publico por primera vez al 1547 (https://aidnac2010.blogspot.com/2009/10/romance-de-fontefrida.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Etimología

No todas las *oes* son iguales.

La RAE tiene razón:

- *do* ← *de o* ← *dē ubī* ("de" + "donde") `latín` <sup>(cf ***ubi**cación*)</sup>

Compáralo con:

- *donde* ← *de onde* ← *dē unde* ("de" + "de donde") `latín`

Al otro lado, la conjunción:

- *o* ← *aut* ("o") `latín`

---

## Uso

La entrada en el diccionario Academia Usual (1884) es la primera en que se describe *do* así:

> #### **Do.**
>
> adv **1. Donde**. Hoy generalmente no se usa más que en poesía. || ant. De donde.

Dado esto, se puede inferir que se usaba hasta el siglo XIX. Por supuesto aún puedes usarlo hoy en día, pero no cuentes con que tu audiencia lo entienda.

---

## Datos

Puedes buscar más precisamente usando términos así (para especificar la categoría gramatical etc) en Google Ngram:

[Google Ngram: *"do_ADV"*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do_ADV&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3)

O puedes usar [el CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html).

Comment: Nota los "restos" de esto en asturiano: *u/ú* es *donde/dónde*. La rara adición de la D sin cambiar el significado es evidenciada por el gallego-portugués y (variante en) asturiano *onde*. Quizás otra pregunta pueda ser cómo es este *de* aparece sin distinción en significado del antiguo *onde*